# Better way to query a ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Assume the model below:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

Is there a better way to get the same result as `foo`?

```
foo = Article.objects.filter(publications=1).filter(publications=2).filter(publications=3).filter(publications=4).filter(publications=5)
```

I tried

```
bar = Article.objects.filter(Q(publications=1) & Q(publications=2) & Q(publications=3) & Q(publications=4) & Q(publications=5))
```

and

```
baz = Article.objects.filter(publications__id__in=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

But they are not the same as `foo`

Comment: Maybe this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#in i.e. use publications__in instead of publications__id__in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the three are not the same: the first one will look for `Article`s that have *at least* `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` *and* `5` as publications.

Te *second* code fragment will return *no* entries, since you here query for an `Article` that has *a* publication that has as primary key `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5` as primary key all for *the same* `Publication`, which is simply not possible.

The last one on the other hand will return `Article`s for which it has at least `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, *or* `5` as publication, so one is sufficient.

You can however simplify the first query to:

```
pubs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

foo = (
    Article.objects.filter(publications__in=pubs)
    .alias(npub=Count('publications'))
    .filter(npub=len(set(pubs)))
)
```

here we thus filter on the publications, but by counting, we ensure that *all* `Publication`s are linked.

Comment: Could you please explain why the alias() function only considers publications with IDs in the range of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], instead of including all publications associated with the article?

Comment: @EddyHD: because of the `.filter(...)` before it, filtering out the rest.